# ASP.Net MVC2 Passing Parameters in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

After using the original MVC for sometime I am getting familiar with MVC 2, but I would like to know whether there is away of passing values from a form, like a user name and password, which is not sent as part of URL when moving on to the next page?

I have a basic form that takes in a few values binding to an entity and then the next thing I do is call my model level for the database. After that I return RedirectToAction.

Can anyone advise me, please?

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect you are loosing all POSTed values that were present in the form. A redirect means a new GET request and a GET request means that if you want to be able to retrieve those values on the target action you have a couple of choices:

- Save them in the database and pass only the id as query string parameter that will allow the target action to retrieve them
- Pass all values as query string parameters
- Use TempData or Session (not recommended)

Comment: why is session not recommended?

Comment: Because it is not RESTful. It is PITA in a web farm and it doesn't scale.

Comment: oh I see, thanks.  It's the easiest way but those are drawbacks indeed. Another option would be not to redirect, but to treat the values in the same program, and only redirect after the processing is done (user validation, etc).

Comment: Thanks, but if for instance you want to encrypt any data that is appended to the URL for security, how can this be done?

Comment: @Andy5, you don't want to do that. You don't want to send any sensitive data over urls, even encrypted.